# Pokemon Evolutions package doesn't get chains right

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I am working on a pokemon bot and I am stuck in somewhere.
I want to make a command to check if a pokemon contains the second pokemon in its evolution line or not. I am using a node.js package called [Evolutions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/evolutions).
Here is code:

```
if (command === 'does') {
  const b = evolution.getEvolutionChain(args[0]);
  const c = args[1]
  if (b.includes(c)) {
    msg.channel.send("True!")
  } else {
    msg.channel.send("False!")
  };
}
```

The code doesn't give an error but it always sends `False!`.
I used in my server (where the bot is) `a!` is the prefix.

```
a!does charmander charmeleon
```

Everything is correct but it always sends `False!`, even if it needs to be `True!`.

Comment: Well, if everything is correct, how can there be an error? ;) What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase there is no error, It just returns false everytime!

Comment: Can you log the values of `args[0]`, `const b` and `const c` and show them to us? It would help figuring out where the problem lies

Comment: @T.Dirks 
Args[0] is charmander
const b is finding evolution line of charmander
const c is args[1] which is charmeleon

Comment: @AshKetchum I know what they do, but can you show their actual values? Like what is `const b` after it gets the evolution line, etc.

Comment: @T.Dirks const b after i type charmander is :
Charmander,
Charmeleon,
Charizard
which is in an array

Comment: If those are the literal values from the array, the error is easy to spot. Since the evolution chain is returned WITH capital letters and you are looking for a value WITHOUT capital letters, it will always return false. The easiest fix is to change all the values (both `const b` as `const c`) into lowercase before checking if the array includes the given evolution

Comment: @T.Dirks thank you a lot! it's now working! you can add this to answers and i will make it working so other peoples get it easily!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `evolution.getEvolutionChain(args[0]);` returns the values with capitalized letters it's easiest if you turn all the values (both the array of evolutions as the user given evolution) to lowercase. After that you can check if the array contains the given evolution.